# How to set font size of a textview equal to its height

Tags: android, android-layout

The code is a simple xml file containing a linear layout.Inside the linear layout , I have two text Views and a lnother linear layout, containing a button.
I want to set the font size equal to height of the textview. We get the height using weight and weight sum method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:text="Coming Soon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/mainscreen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="45"
        android:background="@color/mainscreen">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this programatically.

```
TextView defaultTextView = new TextView(context);
float sourceTextSize = defaultTextView.getTextSize();
TextView.setTextSize(sourceTextSize/getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

The defaultTextView.getTextSize() returns size in pixels and setTextSize(size) takes input as sp, So your text becomes bigger.

Here, instead of directly setting up the text size, first we are converting them according to density.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a shape drawable for textview .

```
<solid android:color="@color/your_background_coler"/>
```

and put it in textview background attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
    We can not set text size like wrap_content,fill_parent or match_parent 
as like textview height so, if you need to set text size equals to 
Textview height than you need to go for fix textview height and text 
size like.... 
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" 
            android:textSize="50dp"/>
```